# Google map Zooming

Tags: swift, google-maps, dictionary, colors, zooming

I'm trying to zoom google map on particular pin from lat long.it working fine but i want to change pin image when zoom in on pin in swift.i have doing like this but there have putting 2 image on same lat long.

```
func zoom(lat: Double, long : Double){
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setValue(1, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)

        // It will animate your camera to the specified lat and long
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: long, zoom: 15)
        self.mapView!.animate(to: camera)
        let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat,longitude: long)
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.map = self.mapView
        marker.icon = UIImage.init(named: "pin-1")

         CATransaction.commit()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a function that detects changes in your zoom level then put a condition that will change the value of your marker icon.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {
 let marker = GMSMarker()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }

   override func loadView() {
    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
        // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        self.view = mapView

    mapView.delegate = self

        // Creates a marker in the coordinate of the map.

        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
        marker.title = "Sydney"
        marker.snippet = "Australia"
        marker.map = mapView
       marker.icon = UIImage(named: "pin_orange")
    }

//This detect the changes in the cameraposition
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
          let zoom = mapView.camera.zoom
          print("map zoom is ",String(zoom))

        //put a condition here to change the icon of your marker
        if zoom > 6 {
            marker.icon = UIImage(named: "icon1")
        }else{
            marker.icon = UIImage(named: "icon2")
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!